# How to open a specific page when a push notification is clicked in Ionic 3 while app is in background?

Tags: ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin

I have integrated PhoneGap push notifications plugin. I am able to receive notifications in Android and i am able to open a specific page when app is in the foreground. I would like to open a specific page when a user clicks on the notifications while app is in background but I am not able to find any solutions. I even tried the link below.

https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59

Here is my code

```
initPushNotification() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      console.warn('Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device');
      return;
    }
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: 'YOUR_SENDER_ID'
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: false,
        sound: 'true'
      },
      windows: {}
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('device token -> ' + data.registrationId);
      //TODO - send device token to server
    });

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('message -> ' + data.message);
      //if user using app and push notification comes
      if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
        // if application open, show popup
        let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'New Notification',
          message: data.message,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ignore',
            role: 'cancel'
          }, {
            text: 'View',
            handler: () => {
              //TODO: Your logic here
              this.nav.push(DetailsPage, { message: data.message });
            }
          }]
        });
        confirmAlert.present();
      } else {
        //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
        //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
        this.nav.push(DetailsPage, { message: data.message });
        console.log('Push notification clicked');
      }
    });

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin' + error));
  }
```

Comment: i am also facing same problem ? How you fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Inject App like;

```
import {App } from "ionic-angular";
constructor(private app: App){...}
```

then;

```
var nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
nav.push(DetailsPage, { message: data.message });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:-

```
this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {'message': data.message});
```

and in Detailspage.ts constructor get this message using Navparams:-

```
message:any;
this.message = this.navParams.get('message');
```

Now you can display this message in detailspage.html using {{message}}